# Using loop for to shorten object name in VB.NET code

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

i have 5 textbox and i want to call its name with for loop , how to do this :

```
  textbox1.backcolor = color.Lightblue
  textbox2.backcolor = color.Lightblue
  textbox3.backcolor = color.Lightblue
  textbox4.backcolor = color.Lightblue
  textbox5.backcolor = color.Lightblue
```

i want to know how to make the code shorter with loop for, so far my only clue is this code :

```
    Public Sub ShortCode
      For i = 1 to 5
      textbox(i).backcolor = color.lightblue
      Next
    End Sub
```

any idea how to make this happen ?

Comment: make sure you check an answer, if one satisfies your question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you stick to your naming convention, you don't need to add the text boxes to an array. Use `Control.Controls`. This function finds controls directly inside some container i.e. `Me.Controls` searches only the form (Me), not inside containers such as panels and group boxes.

```vb
For i = 1 to 5
    CType(Me.Controls("textbox" & i.ToString()), TextBox).BackColor = Color.LightBlue
Next
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls(v=vs.110).aspx

Similar (not identical) solution in one line with LINQ

```vb
Me.Controls.OfType(Of Control).
    Where(Function(c As Control) c.Name.StartsWith("textbox")).
    ToList().ForEach(Sub(c) c.BackColor = Color.Red)
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an array of your TextBox controls and then iterate over them as you suggested.  Below is untested code adapted from http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/846341-array-textbox, but should get you there.

```
Dim textboxes As TextBox()
textboxes = New TextBox() {TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3};

For i = 1 to 3 
textbox(i).backcolor = color.lightblue
```

Answer (score 0):

if the answer above doesn't work for you try this

```
    Public Sub ShortCode
    dim i = 1 
    for i >= 5
     textbox(i).backcolor = color.lightblue
     i = i + 1
    Next

    End Sub
```

Comment: Does that even compile?

Answer (score 0):

Dim TextBoxBag() As TextBox

TextBoxBag = {TextBox1,TextBox2,TextBox3,TextBox4,TextBox5}

For count = 0 to Ubound(TextBoxBag)

TextBoxBag(count).BackColor = Color.LightBlue

Next